# Jboss error at deployment

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I have some issues while doing deployment of a proyect that i'm migrating from WebSphere to JBOSS 6.1

The Java jdk i use with the server and the ide is 1.8.0_144, the project is compiled with java 1.6
Some of the server log is:

```
09:08:07,294 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 582) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    ... 6 more

09:08:07,302 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (HttpManagementService-threads - 9) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([{"deployment" => "PROYECTEAR.ear"}]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
09:08:07,303 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 9) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "PROYECTEAR.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
09:08:08,305 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: PROYECT.war) in 1001ms
09:08:08,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment PROYECTEAR.ear (runtime-name: PROYECTEAR.ear) in 1012ms
09:08:08,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 9) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT
```

by now im deploying with the application plattform, witch throws this error

> Deployment failed: PROYECTEAR.ear: {"outcome" : "failed",
>   "failure-description" : {"JBAS014671: Failed services" :
>   {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT" :
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./PROYECT:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:
>   Failed to start context\n Caused by:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:
>   Failed to start context"}}, "rolled-back" : true}

As far as i can see all the jar dependencies are well compiled at the EAR.

I am quite a newbie, so if more info is needed i'll provide it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 6.1 does not support Java 8. Support for Java 8 started with EAP 6.3.3 (with issues) and EAP 6.4. EAP 6.x is the same codebase as AS7. So whether you're talking about AS6.1 or EAP6.1 you should not use Java 8 to start with. Try using java 7, or better yet, the same version of java your application been compiled with. That will probably help.